# How to allow people to subscribe with recurring payments in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I use Stripe and PayPal. I need a form allowing people to sign up for my subscription. Stripe has the subscription, but not the form. Do Cognito Forms  have the capability to create recurring subscriptions? And if yes, how do I go about that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you want a recommendation, that would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support creating recurring subscriptions.

This feature is on our public Idea Board and definitely has a lot of interest from our customers.  While we have researched adding support for this, we do not currently have a specific timeframe in mind for releasing this capability.

https://trello.com/c/1XpfGKm8/134-subscription-billing-recurring-payments